# Formatting NSDate not working

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following method, which I want to use to return the modified date:

```
- (NSDate *)getCreationDate:(NSFileManager *)fileManager atPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSError *error;
    NSDate *date;
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];

    // Get creation date.
    if (!error) {
        if (fileAttributes != nil) {
            NSDate *creationDate = [fileAttributes fileCreationDate];
            NSString *dateString = [creationDate description];
            NSLog(@"Unformatted Date Created: %@", dateString);

            // Format date.
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
            date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
            NSLog(@"Formatted Date Created: %@", [date description]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"File attributes not found.");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    return date;
}
```

The problem is that the formatted date is coming back as null.

**Output:**

Unformatted Date Created: 2013-02-06 04:44:57 +0000

Formatted Date Created: (null)

Comment: You need to review the documentation. `description` has no defined return format; you're attempting to rely on undocumented behaviour. I suggest you read up again on what an `NSDate` is; you seem to have invented a notion that it has a format when it doesn't. It's just an opaque representation of a particular moment.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code it's hard to know where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's no such thing as a formatted NSDate.** It's just a date with no format. The description method is for debugging and logging and uses whatever format it wants.

NSDateFormatter is used to create an NSString representation of the NSDate with your specified format. Your method could be replaced with this and do exactly the same thing.

```
- (NSDate *)getCreationDate:(NSFileManager *)fileManager atPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];

    // Get creation date.
    if (!error) {
        if (fileAttributes != nil) {
            return [fileAttributes fileCreationDate];
       } else {
            NSLog(@"File attributes not found.");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    return nil;
}
```

When you want to display the date, format it then. Use NSDateFormatter to turn it into a formatted NSString.

In addition, the lines

```
    date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

create a new date, then throw it away. The first line is unnecessary.

Comment: Can whomever was responsible explain the down vote on this answer? It's correct: `NSDate`s don't have a format. The `fileCreationDate` is something you get directly from the attributes. Even given that his use of a date formatter is just plain completely wrong, it's unclear why the original author wants to create a date, then throw it away and replace it with one from the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't incorporate the time zone into the time format, and the format of the hours is wrong. It should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ
```

Comment: It's still returning null with your answer as well. I didn't downvote either btw.

Comment: @gotnull I've made an edit since then - check the format of the date (not just the time) as well. Also make sure that the string doesn't contain any extraneous whitespace.

Comment: @gotnull In this case, please accept & upvote my answer, thanks.

Comment: Go back and look at what the code is doing. It's turning a date into a string, then parsing the string to get the date. You've solved the parsing problem when the entire operation is unnecessary.

Comment: Someone appears to have run down the page, down voting everything; I wouldn't take it personally.

Comment: Well, I observe that the answer had nothing to do with the several things that were wrong with the OP's code.  You merely continued him on his erroneous way.